# Using TestFlight to distribute a Release?

Tags: iphone, testflight

We have an iOS Enterprise Developer License at our company and are about to distribute an in-house developed iphone app.

We've used TestFlight for our beta testing and liked the monitoring features so much we though of distributing the Release version of the app with TestFlight as well.

Do you see any technical or legal problems with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, test flight allows you to modify code in the app. Apple will not like you doing this without them having control, thats the whole reason for the review process. I Would HIGHLY recommend against this

Comment: There is no review process for In-House distributed apps anyway.. right?

Comment: sry my bad mixed up something in my head. yes I don't believe there is a review process because its seen as your own app store isn't it? if thats the case then you might be ok, but I'm sure either way the test flight code monitoring / checking for updates would be quite heavy on the device and network bandwidth, especially if a large number use it. I'm sure you could use it if you wanted but it wasn't designed for this so there may be un foreseen issues. Not sure if it makes sense if you have enterprise account and can update frequently, seems like a waste just for some stats

Comment: yeah, u r maybe right. Might be a waste of performance and bandwidth just for some stats. I think we'll go for [wirelessly distribution](https://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad871e) instead

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an enterprise account. With this you can easily share apps with other people just by sending them a URL. This enables you to not register testusers in your developer account of Apple.

Comment: As I wrote, we have en enterprise account. We're just wondering if we still could use TestFlight to get the crash/session/checkpoint reports in TestFlight.